# correlation of two matrices in R

Tags: r, file

I have two matrices (different rows and same columns). I want to calculate the corelation between the rows of two matrices. (element-wise corelation).the first one is like this:

> ```
> A 2 5
> B 6 9
> c 7 8
> ```

and the second one is like this:

> ```
> D 8 6
> E 1 7
> F 7 9
> ```

in this case the results would be a 3 by 3 matrix (element by element corelation and if possible significance level). how can I make it?

Comment: Do you have more than two columns in your matrices?

Comment: yes I do have 50 columns

Comment: Next time you make an example you might want to add a few more columns in then or specify the dimensions of the actual problem.  With 2 columns you would only ever get either 1 or -1.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
# Create some fake data
set.seed(5) # for reproducibility
mat1 = matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=4)
mat2 = matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5)

cor(t(mat1),t(mat2)) # With compliments to @user20650
```

The output is a matrix of correlation coefficients, where the rows of the output matrix are the row indices of `mat1` and the columns are the row indices of `mat2`.

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.8160882  0.6347404  0.4746797 -0.1497491 -0.4571110
[2,] -0.3021956  0.5039831  0.3204012 -0.2516131  0.6280471
[3,] -0.1188116  0.1798996  0.4537378  0.6036471  0.3732481
[4,]  0.6682962 -0.4815078 -0.5085583 -0.1232551 -0.1088882
```

You can get significance level with `rcorr` from the `Hmisc` package. `rcorr` concatenates the two matrices and returns correlations and significance levels between all pairs of columns. Here's a way to get just the significance levels of correlations *between* each matrix rather than within each matrix (though there may be an easier way).

The transpose function is just to get the rows and columns to correspond between the correlation matrix above and significance matrix returned below. Also note that you can get the correlation matrix from the code below simply by changing `[[3]]` to `[[1]]`. `rcorr` returns a list with the correlation matrix in the first element and the significance matrix in the third element.

```
library(Hmisc)
t(sapply(1:nrow(mat1), function(x) {
    sapply(1:nrow(mat2), function(y) {
      rcorr(mat1[x,],mat2[y,])[[3]][1,2]
    })
  }))

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.09202147 0.2499648 0.4191522 0.8100486 0.4389450
[2,] 0.62117186 0.3866162 0.5991440 0.6830495 0.2565734
[3,] 0.84908109 0.7721863 0.4427686 0.2810484 0.5360431
[4,] 0.21755702 0.4115164 0.3815924 0.8434650 0.8616337
```